# Using a mathabx style \rightsquigarrow in a tikz-cd commutative diagram

Tags: arrows, tikz-cd, commutative-diagrams, mathabx

I'm trying to make these two style arrows line up. Below is a minimal working example.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathabx, tikz-cd}

\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=math font}

\begin{document}
     \begin{align*}
         A \rightsquigarrow B
     \end{align*}
     \begin{center}
         \begin{tikzcd}
             A \arrow[r, rightsquigarrow] & B
         \end{tikzcd}
     \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image: the first display uses a mathabx rightsquigarrow, while the second only uses the mathabx arrow tip, while the length of the arrow is an amssymb rightsquigarrow]

My problem is that rightsquigarrows appear in terms of the amssymb design when placed in a commutative diagram. It's angular and jagged, while I'm trying to make it identical to the actual squiggly arrow provided by mathabx.

Answer (score 1):

I think `tikz-cd` doesn't have that option.

You may try to do something with `snake` decoration.

This is the best I can do:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath, mathabx, tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing,shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\tikzcdset{arrow style=tikz,
    squigarrow/.style={
        decoration={
        snake, 
        amplitude=.4mm,
        segment length=2mm
        }, 
        rounded corners=.2pt,
        decorate
        }
    }

\begin{document}
     \begin{align*}
         A \rightsquigarrow B
     \end{align*}
     \[
     \begin{tikzcd}
         A \ar[r, squigarrow] & B
     \end{tikzcd}
     \]
\end{document}
```

[image]